# ng-change event is not triggering when date change is fired

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript

Hi I am new to angular js. Currently my scenario is when i change the date it should trigger the method where it opens the modal .but in my case i am using ng-change event to call the method where by using this the call is not fired on date change.
but if i use the ng-click method on click of date field will open the modal which should not happen on change of date only it should open modal.
so how i can achieve this?

HTML code:

```html
<div class="input-wrap-container row">
  <field ng-model="requisition.validityStartDate" class="col-xs-4"
         editable="true"
         ng-change ="validityStartDate(requisition.validityStartDate)">
  </field>`
</div>
```

This is my JS code`:

```
var validityStartDate = function (validityStartDate) {
    newValueStartDate = validityStartDate;
    debugger
    if (newValueStartDate != null && newValueStartDate != oldValueStartDate) {

        var apprModalId = "changeValidityDates";

        $element.find('#'+ apprModalId).modal("show");
        oldValueStartDate = newValueStartDate;
        newValueStartDate = null;

        $element.find('#'+ apprModalId).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            console.log("submit-req error modal shown");

        //scope.buttonActionReqError = response;
        });   
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> Evaluate the given expression when the user changes the input.[angularjs doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

Since you are not using an input field, `ngChange` will not fire.

Change `<field>` to `<input>`

**UPDATE TO MATCH COMMENT**

[onKeyup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup)

I guess you could do  `ng-keyup="expression"` if you wanted, or keyDown or anything else that is triggered by a keypress.

Comment: In my case its bit difficult to change because in entire application this field is used design would be changed so is there any other approach?

Comment: I guess you could due on keyup